# SimpleMailMessage is not working

Tags: spring, sendmail

im using spring SimpleMailMessage,whenever i try to send mail function i get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'original' message argument cannot be null
```

My spring.xml

```
   <bean id="MailSender" class="com.util.MailSender">

    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"/>
    <property name="templateMessage" ref="templateMessage"/>

</bean>
```

MailSenderClass:

```
  private MailSender mailSender;
    private SimpleMailMessage templateMessage;

    //getter and setter
    public void sendMail(String content, List<String> listEmail){
        SimpleMailMessage[] mailMessageArray = new SimpleMailMessage[listEmail.size()];
        Iterator<String> iterator = listEmail.iterator();

        for (int index = 0; iterator.hasNext(); index ++){

    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage(this.templateMessage);
    String toAddress = iterator.next(); 
         message.setTo(toAddress);
     message.setText(content);  
         mailMessageArray[index] = message;

    }
         this.mailSender.send(mailMessageArray);
     }
```

Action Bean Class :

```
 private MailSender mailSender=new MailSender();

      public void ReSend(){
         mailSender.sendMail(listBEeans[i].getEmailContent(),listEmail);
          //able to pass the content and listEmails correctly

}
```

Did i miss any configurations in my action bean? Thank you

Comment: This problem is not JSF related.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your bean is creating a local reference to MailSender instead of using the injected dependency (assuming you created one). Somewhere you should have:

```
AnObject
{
...
MailSender mailsender = (MailSender)context.getBean("mailSender");
...
}
```

And your bean should then say:

```
private MailSender = AnObject.getMailSender();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your template used in the constructor is `null`. It cannot be.

From the code of `SimpleMailMessage`:

```
public SimpleMailMessage(SimpleMailMessage original) {
    Assert.notNull(original, "The 'original' message argument cannot be null");
...
```

Check if your bean templateMessage is really set to something or remove it from the MailSender and use the no-args constructor.

Comment: ,thanks for the response.i tried to test without argument constructor,still getting this issue,

Comment: well, did you check why your bean `templateMessage` configured in `<property name="templateMessage" ref="templateMessage"/>` is null?

Comment: yes,the same function is being used in one backend class where mailSender class intialized like with @Resource annotation.i tried to use same way to my frontend action class but it throws an exception like 'myactionbean is not bound in this context(javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:)